# How to interact with fillable PDF form in iPad browser without any plugins?

Tags: forms, ipad, pdf

We are having a problem to interact with fillable PDF form in iPad browser. We tried to enter ther value and select the option in the fillable PDF form fields.But we can not access the fields. They are all in read-only mode when we are open in iPad Browser. Is that any way to interact fillable PDF form in iPad browser without any plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you will be able to fill form fields in a PDF document depends on which reader you use on the iPad. Adobe Reader does support this for suitably created documents. A number of other solutions (present in the app store do too).

As far as I know as of today you need an application to allow this (i.e. you cannot rely on the PDF engine delivered by Apple).

Comment: Our requirement to view and interact fillable PDF in iPad only (Using any browser). But we can not install any PDF plugin for that. Even if we install Adobe Reader in iPad also the browser is not taking any plugin to interact with the fillable PDF. Right now we are using the Safari browser and it opens the PDF in Default previewer mode in which we are not able to interact/input data into the PDF file. Kindly suggest your inputs

Comment: I can only repeat my comment from above: "As far as I know as of today you need an application to allow this (i.e. you cannot rely on the PDF engine delivered by Apple)." If your requirement is to allow this using any browser a user could use on iPad, the answer is that your requirement to my knowledge is impossible with todays technology...